# CSS Border image from a url - not working

Tags: html, css, url, border-image

I would like to style the border image the same as in w3school example: http://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_border-image.

But when I tried it in my desktop, https://jsfiddle.net/tangjeen/6yLtmb98/ the result of the border image is not the same.
Would appreciate if you could help me. Thank you.

```
<div class="row" id="round">
   <p>sdfsfsdf</p>
</div>

#round{
   -webkit-border-image: url(http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/border.png) 30 30 round; /* Safari 3.1-5 */
   -o-border-image: url(http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/border.png) 30 30 round; /* Opera 11-12.1 */
   border-image: url(http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/border.png) 30 30 round; 
   background-color: lightyellow;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make sure the `border-width: 15px;/*your value*/` and `border-style: solid; /*needed for Firefox*/` are set.

Or the shorthand way `border: 15px solid transparent;`. ALSO need to make sure it's set BEFORE `border-image` rule.

```css
#round {
    border-width: 15px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-image: url("https://i.imgur.com/BzbWBYA.png") 30 30 round; 
    background-color: lightyellow;
}
```

```html
<div id="round">
    <p>hello world!</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you explain why `border` need to be placed on top ? `border` is it overwriting something in `border-image` ? It is supposed to set style, color and size only no ? I tried to write `border: 15px solid initial` on bottom, it works BUT border size is not correct. Thanks.

Comment: I suppose `transparent` make also image transparent... And it seems like `initial` value is considered like `none` because it's the default value of `border-style`. But if you use it like this: `border: 15px initial`, the size is also ignored and resetted to `medium` (the dfault value of `border-width`)

Comment: @FLefèvre agreed, it's none for default, according to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-style)

Comment: plus one for "ALSO need to make sure it's set BEFORE border-image rule."

Answer (score 2):

To resolve this problem you can also adjust the `border-image-width` and add a `padding` to your block:

```
#round{ 
    -webkit-border-image: url(http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/border.png) 30 30 round; /* Safari 3.1-5 */
    -o-border-image: url(http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/border.png) 30 30 round; /* Opera 11-12.1 */
    border-image: url(http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/border.png) 30 30 round; 
    border-image-width: 15px;
    padding: 5px 0px 5px 15px;
    background-color: lightyellow;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I'd use this :

```
#round img{
border: imgpath;
}
```

**EDIT**

By the way, your code works... look : http://jsfiddle.net/5Lyw6qek/

Comment: Where is the image here ? OP don't need an image but a border-image. Not the same...